# How to configure logs of multiple groovy file into one log file?

Tags: logging, groovy, log4j, slf4j

I am using FileAppender to create log file and ConsoleAppender to display logs in console. Thereafter I'm calling other groovy file from the existing one and I want to log all details of other files also into one log file. I have tried passing the existing log as well as FileAppender variable into other as argument but it's not working. And I'm using @Log4j.

Please suggest me how to handle this.